# Do you wash before consuming already cut parts of fruits?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, pomegranate

There are some super markets and stores that sell the fruits already cut.
E.g. containers with pomegranate seeds.
In such cases, do you usually wash them before consumption?

Answer (score 1):

It likely depends on what you’re doing with the fruit.

Food that has been packaged like this should have been done in a hygienic environment so there isn’t a significant risk of bacteria or similar contamination.  It should have been washed before cutting (and possibly peeled) reducing pesticide contamination.

But similar to how there are times when you would or wouldn’t rinse canned fruit, I suspect that there might be reasons to wash the fruit… but in general, you shouldn’t need to.

However, if the container is bulging, that’s a sign that there’s been some sort of microbial activity (such as fermentation), and for safety you should probably avoid it rather than just try to wash it.

Comment: `if the container is bulging` what does that mean? By the way, the container is a simple plastic one with sealing on top. I guess the peeling you mention is for other fruits, do you need to peel pomegranate seeds?

Comment: @Jim I would read that as a more generic description. Plus removing the seeds from a pomegranate isn’t that different from peeling, sort of.

Comment: By ‘bulging’, I mean that the top is pushed up like the container is pressurized.  This is a bad sign in general when you food that has been stored.  (I’ve seen packages of meat in the store that look like balloons… And it wasn’t one of those ‘pillow packs’ where they do it Iintentionally